# How to get all data for next 24 hours from selected date in db2?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, db2

I have database table in db2 with fields

| Date(Numeric) | Time(Seconds) | Account | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1191231 | 12453 | 24562 | 8500 |
| 1191231 | 16253 | 24562 | 7600 |
| 1200101 | 76253 | 24562 | 6500 |
| 1200101 | 92253 | 24562 | 2500 |
| 1200101 | 15253 | 24562 | 2500 |

Here, 1191231 means --> 2019-12-31 and 12000101 --> 2020-01-01

I want to select all data between 1191231 from time 16200 and 1200101 to time 16200 of the date.

In short I want data from 16200(04:30 AM) seconds of 1191231 to 16200(04:30 AM) seconds of 1200101...I hope you got my point.

Output I want is

| Date(Numeric) | Time(Seconds) | Account | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1191231 | 16253 | 24562 | 7600 |
| 1200101 | 15253 | 24562 | 2500 |

In this, I get the data with time between 4:30AM of 2019-12-31 till 4:30AM  2020-01-01 (for 24 hours time)

I have used this SQL query

```
select Date, Time, Account, Amount
from Customer
where account = '24562'
  and Date BETWEEN 1191231 AND 1200101
  and time > 16500
```

Please, help me to get the solution.....Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the SQL you tried? Which version and platform of Db2? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You provide the inital SQL statement and the community helps with the errors. What time is "92253" (row 4)?

Comment: DB2 does have proper date and timestamp data types: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=columns-date-time-timestamp-data-types

Comment: @data_henrik I have used above query but this only filters data  from 2019-12-31 4:30 AM to 2020-01-01 11:59 PM

Comment: @jarlh I cannot change the data type of date and time, I can only access the DB2.

Comment: @data_henrik 92253 is the time in seconds and 16200 is 4:30 AM

Comment: Yes, but how do you interpret 92253 as time? IMHO that value does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WHERE BIGINT (DATE) * 86400 + TIME BETWEEN
BIGINT (1191231) * 86400 + 16200
AND
BIGINT (1200101) * 86400 + 16200
```